# How to redirect to 404 page if user wants to access a specific page which requires login authentication in angular-meteor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, redirect, meteor, angular-meteor

I am using Angular-Meteor.

I have a page that requires login authentication.

e.g: http://localhost:3000/verifyPhone

I want to redirect the user to: http://localhost:3000/404 if he is not logged in and trying to access that restricted page.

Here is my routes file:

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

    $stateProvider
    .state('verifyPhone', {
      url: "/verifyPhone",
      templateUrl: "client/www/views/verifyPhone.html",
      controller: "SMSVerificationController"
    });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

How can I peform redirection here?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [**`resolve`**](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve) object to declare your dependency to **[`requireUser()`](http://www.angular-meteor.com/api/auth)**:

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
    $stateProvider
    .state('verifyPhone', {
      url: "/verifyPhone",
      templateUrl: "client/www/views/verifyPhone.html",
      controller: "SMSVerificationController",
      resolve: {
        "currentUser": function ($meteor) {
          return $meteor.requireUser();
        }
      }
    });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

---

After that, you need to catch the `requireUser` promise error and redirect the user to your 404 page:

```
app.run(function ($rootScope, $state) {
  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
    if (error === 'AUTH_REQUIRED') $state.go('404');
  });
});
```